# How do i update latest id in one tab or window while inserting records in a different tab or window?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, csv

I have this in one file. It displays the latest id. let's call this list-display.php

```
<div class="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function refresh_div() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'list-select.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(results) {
            jQuery(".result").html(results);
        }
    });
}
t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

In list-select.php I have this.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".DB_NAME2.".list_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo $id;
}
```

Here is what upload and insert script looks like. Person uploads csv file and the data of csv goes into database table. This one is called list-upload-insert.php

```
<?php
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {
    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".DB_NAME2.".list_data (first, last, address, city, state, zip, company, tracking_number, misc1, misc2, misc3, misc4, misc5, misc6, list) VALUES ('".addslashes($data[0])."', '".addslashes($data[1])."', '".addslashes($data[2])."', '".addslashes($data[3])."', '".addslashes($data[4])."', '".addslashes($data[5])."', '".addslashes($data[6])."', '".addslashes($data[7])."', '".addslashes($data[8])."', '".addslashes($data[9])."', '".addslashes($data[10])."', '".addslashes($data[11])."', '".addslashes($data[12])."', '".addslashes($data[13])."', '".addslashes($data[14])."')");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    $done = "yes";
    //redirect
    //header('Location: list-upload-insert.php?success=1'); //changed to done variable instead of header redirect
    //die;
}
if ($done=="yes") {
    echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; //generic success notice
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    Choose your file: <br />
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In all 3 files I have a global include at the top, and the global include has database connection info. For the SELECT and INSERT queries, I specify a different database, or else it will use a default database, which is not what I need to use in this instance.

While uploading and inserting records in one tab or window, I would like the other tab or window to refresh with the latest id number every second, but it's not working. The display page stays frozen until all of the records are done inserting, then the id refreshes to the latest id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). `addslashes()` is **NOT** a defence, and essentially useless for anything sql-related.

Comment: Are you using sessions? If so, try to call `session_write_close();` before your `do ... while()` loop.

Comment: What table type do you use, innodb or myisam?

Comment: I'm using innodb and sessions as well.

Comment: session write close seemed to do the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using sessions, then you're probably facing a session blocking problem. list-upload-insert.php locks session file exclusively to protect session integrity and list-select.php have to wait until the lock is released.

You can use `session_write_close()`([see doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)) function to release the lock earlier. If you release it before your `do ... while` loop, the other request won't have to wait until import completes.

```
    // don't lock session for the whole import
    session_write_close();

    // loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".DB_NAME2.".list_data (first, last, address, city, state, zip, company, tracking_number, misc1, misc2, misc3, misc4, misc5, misc6, list) VALUES ('".addslashes($data[0])."', '".addslashes($data[1])."', '".addslashes($data[2])."', '".addslashes($data[3])."', '".addslashes($data[4])."', '".addslashes($data[5])."', '".addslashes($data[6])."', '".addslashes($data[7])."', '".addslashes($data[8])."', '".addslashes($data[9])."', '".addslashes($data[10])."', '".addslashes($data[11])."', '".addslashes($data[12])."', '".addslashes($data[13])."', '".addslashes($data[14])."')");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```